# Python - Tkinter - Message widget not always updating

Tags: python, tkinter

I've written a small app and I've gotten it working with a simple GUI in Tkinter, and everything pretty much functions as it should, but I want to add a little bit of polish.

I have a message widget that I use to give status updates to the user, basically just single lines of text for errors or to let them know something is happening in the background. I'm able to change the text in the message widget using a `StringVar`, but the problem I'm running into is that it doesn't seem to update every time I tell it to.

Specifically, I have a button in the app that parses a bunch of data and typically takes several seconds to complete. When the user pushes the button, the message widget updates to the "processing..." text as I want it to, but if there was previously text displayed in the message widget when that button is pushed, the new text appears on top of it. As the "processing" text is shorter than the previous text, the window ends up showing some of both text messages until parsing is complete.

To address this, I tried updating the variable for the message widget to be blank before changing the message to "processing" but the behavior remains unchanged. I'm quite new with Tkinter, and the documentation for the update stuff isn't making a ton of sense to me.

Here is an extremely simplified version of my code, I hope it gets the point across.

```
    import Tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.text = tk.StringVar()
        self.text.set("A semi long text string abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

        text_entry = tk.Entry(self, width = 50)
        text_entry.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 5, padx = 10)
        status_msg = tk.Message(self, width = 300, textvariable = self.text)
        status_msg.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = tk.W, pady = 5)
        btn_submit = tk.Button(self, text="Test Button", width = 12, command = self.test)
        btn_submit.grid(row = 1, column = 0, pady = 5, padx = 10)


    def test(self):
        self.text.set("")
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        self.text.set("Starting to process...")
        self.master.update_idletasks()
        for i in range(5000):
            print i
        self.text.set("Complete!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.master.title('Tk test')
app.master.geometry('400x100')
app.mainloop()
```

EDIT: To better explain what happens that I'm trying to get rid of, here is a screenshot of the message widget while the processing is going on. You can see the "Processing Keys..." but just after that you can see where the previous message text is still there just before the word valid (which is part of the previous message and I don't want to be there at all. [message widget screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11662267/example.png)

EDIT2: I've completely replaced the code above with something that does replicate exactly the problem I'm running into with my program (at least as far as the message text being displayed is concerned), that the message text never changes to "" (blank), but rather the processing message ends up on top of the previous message with some of both of them being displayed.

Furthermore, initially I had the loop go to 10000, and I noticed that in that case Windows actually showed the app window as not responding until it finished. I'm really not sure if that's related to the issue I'm having though.

Comment: Does this code exhibit the same problem as your real code? It doesn't seem possible from what you've described. What you've described I would expect to see if you created the message widget more than once snd placed it in the same row and column each time.

Comment: The advices here are really helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The code above does not have the same problem as my real code, but I'm assuming that's because it's lacking several dozen lines of loops and data being processed, and without that there's no delay when updating the variable (at least that's my guess as to what's going on.I definitely did not create the same widget (or any) widget more than once. The problem with it showing two different text messages at the same time only occurs while the loops that process the data are running.

Comment: I edited my question to include a screenshot of what is happening that I'm trying to stop from happening.

Comment: "The code above does not have the same problem as my real code" - how can we possibly diagnose a problem when you don't give us the code that shows the problem?  Please take the time to create a program that exhibits the problem, or you're just wasting our time.

Comment: My apologies, I thought that my explanation was sufficient to demonstrate what was happening. It's not super creative or pretty, but I have replaced all the code in my question to something that is having the exact same problem my program is having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it's a proper solution to the problem, but I have discovered a workaround that appears to get the job done, at least as far as the widget appearance is concerned.

Editing the first line in the test function that the button calls from `self.text.set("")` to `self.text.set("                                                                        ")` successfully clears the message text in the window before the next message appears, and thus removes the ugly overlap while the processing is going on.